# TYPO3 typo3_forum I dob't see form for posting

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18. I have femanager and typo3_forum. Problem is that I don't see form for posting in the forum ? where is it ? Where may be a problem ?

Comment: Did you include all necessary static TypoScript templates?

Comment: No I did't. But when I include - I have next problem: when I click to topic it redirect me to the main page. I check html and see that all link has empty attribute href.

Comment: Please use the manual http://typo3-forum.readthedocs.io/en/master/Configuration/Installation/Index.html